# Amazon Lambda function and Cognito : Add new user in existing user pool using a lambda function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I would know if we can create a lambda function to add a new user to a specific user pool, if yes have you any example that explain which role to create for this lambda function using nodeJs ?.

Answer (score 4):

If i understood your question correctly follow these steps:

- In your aws console navigate to "Identity and Access Management (IAM)"
- Select "Roles" and look for your lambda function, click on it.
- Under "Permissions" click on "Attach Policies" and look for "AmazonCognitoPowerUser", this policy will give your lambda full access to Cognito User Pools.

Create new user code example:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const cognito = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
const params = {
    ClientId: "The ID of the client associated with the user pool",
    Username: "My Username",
    Password: "My Password",
};
cognito.signUp(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

[Take a look at this api documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#signUp-property)

Comment: do you have any lambda function example after attaching AmazonCognitoPowerUser policy ?